# Link not reacting on click in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have some links which I have styled using some [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) CSS. The problem is that the links don't follow to the url specified in the `href` attribute. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y87at/2/).

Comment: Have you tested your code in other place (as in your computer locally stored), or just in JSFiddle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the normal behavior in JSFiddle: the page forbids opening links on the same frame. For testing purposes, however, you can add 'target="_blank"' to the 'a' tags to open the links in another window.